# docker ADD command throwing file not found

Tags: java, linux, docker

I have a docker image that uses the `ADD` command to [copy and unzip](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) a file called `dependencies.tar`.
The build command works perfectly fine locally, but it keeps complaining that the file is not to be found in bitbucket pipelines. on top of that when I do an `ls` command in the pipeline I can see the file there.

EDIT:

I have also tried to use the `ADD` command with a relative path like so `ADD proxy-service/build/libs/dependencies.tar /build/libs/`

```
FROM adaptavist/all-tools AS build

COPY . /code

WORKDIR /code

ARG NEXUS_USERNAME
ARG NEXUS_PASSWORD
ARG NEXUS_URL

ENV NEXUS_USERNAME=$NEXUS_USERNAME
ENV NEXUS_PASSWORD=$NEXUS_PASSWORD
ENV NEXUS_URL=$NEXUS_URL

RUN configure_maven.sh
RUN ./gradlew proxy-service:build proxy-service:tarDepsForDockerJava11 -i --stacktrace -PisJava11

RUN ls -l proxy-service/build/libs

ADD /code/proxy-service/build/libs/dependencies.tar /build/libs/
COPY proxy-service/build/libs/proxy-service.jar /build/

FROM gcr.io/distroless/java:11

COPY --from=build /build /app

EXPOSE 5061

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-XshowSettings:vm", "-XX:MinRAMPercentage=50", "-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80", "-cp", "proxy-service.jar:libs/*", "ratpack.groovy.GroovyRatpackMain"]
```

bitbucket pipelines error:

```sh
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5m 26s
10 actionable tasks: 10 executed
Stopped 1 worker daemon(s).
Removing intermediate container 8e83ff85f7ed
 ---> ddeb967de678
Step 12/19 : RUN ls -l proxy-service/build/libs
 ---> Running in c952752f4298
total 62924
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      64286720 Jul  9 05:43 dependencies.tar
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root         12288 Jul  9 05:43 libs
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root        129325 Jul  9 05:39 proxy-service.jar
Removing intermediate container c952752f4298
 ---> c3572b086609
Step 13/19 : ADD /code/proxy-service/build/libs/dependencies.tar /build/libs/
ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat code/proxy-service/build/libs/dependencies.tar: file does not exist
```

any idea what could be the problem here? and how to solve it?

Comment: Running `ls` inside Dockerfile shows you what's inside the image but I guess you want to add a file from outside. And it seems there is no `dependencies.tar` near the Dockerfile.

Comment: You cannot use ADD with  an absolute path. Dockers build context is in the folder you're executing.

Comment: jokarl i have also done that and get the same error

Comment: @anemyte if that's the case how should I do then?

Comment: I think there is some confusion here. As @anemyte said, when you run `ls` you get the contents of your container, not the host. If you run `ls -l` from a pipeline step, then you will get what you expect. From where you run docker build, any child files of that directory will be available. So it seems your container already contains a `dependencies.tar`, but you also try to copy one from an absolute path from the bitbucket host. If you show your pipeline I could help more.

Comment: @jokarl on point. I was confused. however at this point I want to unpack the tar file in the docker file and put it in the destination folder `build/libs` which should have nothing to do with the pipeline context

Comment: If the file is already in the container, don't use ADD. To execute commands on that file use `RUN tar xzf dependencies.tar --directory=/build/libs`

Answer (score 1):

the problem related to the some confusion between the work directory inside your image  and what you have inside your bitbucket runner , what you need to do first of all :

- Verify where is the current path of your code pulled by the runner
- Display the current path inside the runner using **pwd** to get the path after use **ls** to display the content .
- Be sure that your dockerfile and the file to be copied are exist inside the runner and get path for each two .

Notice : **The File to copy is depend to the location in your code repo not to the workdir**